# MySQL: Rows concatenation

Tags: mysql, concatenation

May be this is really a simple question, thanks in advance.

What I currently have:

```
+-----+---+---+---+---+
| sid | a | b | c | d |
+-----+---+---+---+---+
| 123 |   |   |   | 4 |
| 123 |   | 2 |   |   |
| 123 |   |   | 3 |   |
| 123 | 1 |   |   |   |
| 456 |   | 5 |   |   |
| 456 |   |   | 6 |   |
| 789 |   |   |   | 8 |
| 789 | 7 |   |   |   |
+-----+---+---+---+---+
```

What I am trying to get:

```
+-----+------+------+------+------+
| sid |  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
| 123 | 1    | 2    | 3    | 4    |
| 456 |      | 5    | 6    |      |
| 789 | 7    |      |      | 8    |
+-----+------+------+------+------+
```

How such "rows concatenation" could be done in MySQL?

Comment: 'What I currently have:' - is that what your data looks like or the result of a query you have written?

Comment: 'What I currently have:' is the result of the other big query.

Comment: Given the output from your big query I suspect that you haven;t conditionally aggregated the totals. If you don't want to refactor the big query I would wrap it in another query along the lines suggested by Arnaud Peralta. On the other hand you could publish sample data and expected output as text together with a simplified version of your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `MAX()` aggregation function with a `GROUP BY` clause in your query.

```
SELECT sid, MAX(a), MAX(b), MAX(c), MAX(d)
FROM table
GROUP BY sid
```

I used `MAX()` because it will filter the NULL values with others values.

More explanation here : [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html)